# computing ROC AUC with random forest

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, roc, auc

I use random forest classifier in a multi class problem.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(()
rf.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

And then for prediction:

```
pred = rf.predict(test_X)
```

So then I want to compute the `roc_auc_score` like so:

```
roc_value = roc_auc_score(test_y, pred, average='weighted', 
    multi_class='ovr',labels=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

But this gives an error:

```
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in ROC AUC, `pred` needs to be probabilities, not predicted labels. In your case, it is a multiclass classification problem, so `pred` needs to be a matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_classes)`. To get it you just need to use `predict_proba` instead of `predict`:

```
pred = rf.predict_proba(test_X)
```